# How to change start day in TimeGrouper in python

Tags: python

In Python, `TimeGrouper(freq='W')` starts counting from Monday to Sunday. How to start from Saturday to Friday?

Comment: What is `TimeGrouper`?

Comment: [The documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) *might* be a good start.

Comment: It is used to group data in a weekly basis. For example, you have data of 1 month expenditure. You want to know the weekly expenditure, so you group data in 4 weeks and compute their sum. But this function starts to count on every Monday to Sunday.

Comment: What you needed to say is that it came from `pandas`. Anyway, have a look at the doc. I'm not really sure, but `convention` might be what you're looking for.